# PowerShell Export-csv writes empty string for a NULL database value. Can it be told to write nothing?

Tags: mysql, powershell, csv

Using PowerShell 4.0 and SQL-Server, I want to merge records from one database to another. I use export-csv and import-csv. I export from one database to a csv file, and import from the csv file  to a temporary table in another database, for subsequent MERGE.

TableA is

```
    ([ID] int not null,
     [Name] varchar(25) not null,
     [StartDate] datetime null,
     [Department] varchar(25) not null)
```

Values are ID=1, Name=Joe, StartDate=NULL, Department=Sales

exportTable.ps1  (Ignoring database config)

```
Invoke Sqlcmd ("SELECT FROM TableA WHERE ID=1") | Export-Csv -path a.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

This results in a.csv

```
"ID","Name","StartDate","Department"
"1","Joe","","Sales"
```

import Table.ps1

```
CreateTable TableATemporary
    ([ID] int not null,
     [Name] varchar(25) not null,
     [StartDate] datetime null)

Import-Csv a.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $allValues = "'"+($_.Psobject.Properties.Value -join "','") + "'"
Invoke Sqlcmd ("INSERT INTO TableATemporary VALUES $allValues")
```

This gives a table of
Values are ID=1, Name=Joe, StartDate=1900-01-01 00:00:00:000, Department=Sales

Rather than a null entry, the datetime field is a default value because the field in the csv file is ""

Is there any way for the Export-Csv cmdlet to write nothing to the csv file for the empty fields in the database, instead of ""  ?

Comment: Hopefully no one in your database ever has a name like `O'Brien` or Department like `Men's Wear`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cpt.Whale's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70776267/45375) shows how to *unconditionally* represent empty-string field values without embedded quoting (`''`) [*update*: should be `NULL`] in the argument list constructed for the SQL statement.

If you want explicit control over *which fields* should act this way, you can try the following (simplified example):

```sh
[pscustomobject] @{ ID = '1'; Name = 'Joe'; StartDate = ''; Department = '' } | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $_.psobject.Properties.ForEach({
        $quoteChar = "'"
        $name, $value = $_.Name, $_.Value
        # Determine whether to use (unquoted) NULL if the value is the empty string.
        switch ($name) {
          'StartDate' { if ($value -eq '') { $quoteChar = ''; $value = 'NULL' } }
          # Handle other fields here, as needed.
        }
        '{0}{1}{0}' -f $quoteChar, $value, $quoteChar
      }) -join ','
  }
```

Output (note how the empty-string for `StartDate` resulted in unquoted `NULL`, whereas the one for `Department` is the quoted empty string):

```sh
'1','Joe',NULL,''
```

Note:

- Ideally, whether to quote or not should be guided by the *data types* of the values, but CSV data is by definition all *string*-typed.
- You can implement a data-type mapping of sorts by extending the `switch` statement above, so that, say, numeric fields are *always* used *unquoted* (e.g., as a `switch` branch for a numeric `Age` field: `'Age' { $quoteChar = '' }`).

Comment: Many thank guys. I was hoping there would be an optional argument to Import-Csv, but I guess not. I was going down the route of dealing with each value explicitly as you are both suggesting. As @mklement0 notes, data types should be inspected so I can distinguish between an empty varChar and null int, datetime etc.

Comment: I tried @Cpt.Whale's solution but of course got an incorrect syntax error on the empty field.  Replacing '' with NULL works:
    
Import-Csv a.csv | ForEach-Object {
    # convert empty strings to null
    $allValues = '"' + (($_.Psobject.Properties.Value | ForEach-Object { 
        if($_){"'$_'"} else{"NULL"} }) -join ',') + '"'
    Invoke-Sqlcmd ("INSERT INTO TableATemporary VALUES $allValues")
}

Comment: Good point, @mikec - I've updated the answer accordingly, which now uses a `switch` statement that indirectly allows you to implement a data-type mapping by field name. However, if the modified form of Cpt.Whale's solution is sufficient for you, I suggest letting him know, and, once his answer is amended, accepting it.

Comment: After inspecting the 15 tables I am importing, I have used @mklement0's solution which handles a general case as well as specific case. Luckily I have no nullable fields of a varchar data type. A NULL and an empty string both export as an empty string and the exported csv table contains no information about the original value. This is important for validating a round-trip of export and import for a use case of restoring from a backup database.

Answer (score 2):

`Import-Csv` always returns blank strings, but there are plenty of ways to set those values to `$null` if they're empty. For example, here I check for blank values before joining them:

```sh
Import-Csv a.csv | ForEach-Object {
    # convert empty strings to null
    $allValues = '"' + (($_.Psobject.Properties.Value | ForEach-Object { 
        if($_){"'$_'"} else{''} }) -join ',') + '"'
    Invoke-Sqlcmd ("INSERT INTO TableATemporary VALUES $allValues")
}
```

Now it no longer sets empty strings in `$allvalues`:

```
"'1','Joe',,'Sales'"
```

---

I recommend using `Write-SqlTableData` for importing rather than running sqlcmd for each row, but it's just an efficiency thing.